# Is there another way to write the data in the files?

Tags: c#

I'm doing a project about decompress of `tar` or `tar.gz` files, I visit lots of websites, and I have already done these features, but now, I need to investigate the methods to speed up this project. 
Most are using `TarInputStream` to open and read compress files, and use `streamWriter` to write the data from compress file into the new create file(empty file), I'm using `streamWriter` to combine with thread.

My option is to use each thread to catch the data from the compress file, one thread one file(if the compression contain lot of files), and all threads run together, or give it a thread and ignore it, but when I run my project .exe, it will appear this message

> The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process

So, I think maybe streamWriter have some problem in thread safe.

here is my code

```
//write the data from compress file into new file 
    public static void StreamWriterFun(string pathToTar , string[] args, List<byte[]> mydata)
    {
        string[] str = new string[3];
        for (int i = 0; i < args.Length; i++)
        {
            str[i] = args[i];
        }
    string directoryName = "";

    long size = 0;
    if (pathToTar != "")
        directoryName = Path.GetDirectoryName(pathToTar) + "\\";

    string fileName = Path.GetFileName(pathToTar);

    Directory.CreateDirectory(str[1] + "\\" + directoryName);

    if (fileName != "")
    {
        if ((File.Exists(str[1] + "\\" + directoryName + fileName)) || (!File.Exists(str[1] + "\\" + directoryName + fileName)))
        {
            string test = "";
            using (FileStream streamWriter = File.Create(str[1] + "\\" + directoryName + fileName))
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < mydata.Count; i++)
                {
                    streamWriter.Write(mydata[i], 0, mydata[i].Length);
                }
                streamWriter.Close();
            }
        }
    }
}

public static void TGZWriteCharacters(string[] args)
{
    //args[] define
    string[] str = new string[3];
    for (int i = 0; i < args.Length; i++)
    {
        str[i] = args[i];
    }
    try
    {
        Program file = new Program();
        file.ExtractGZipSample(str[0], str[1]);

        string[] filePaths = Directory.GetFiles(@str[1], "*.tar", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly);
        str[2] = filePaths[0];

        if (str[1] == "")
            str[1] = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();
        if (!str[1].EndsWith("\\"))
            str[1] = str[1] + "\\";// C:\Tar.gz

        ArrayList myList = new ArrayList();

        using (TarInputStream s = new TarInputStream(File.OpenRead(str[2])))// C:\python.tar
        {
            TarEntry theEntry;

            while ((theEntry = s.GetNextEntry()) != null)
            {
                myList.Add(theEntry.Name);
            }
            s.Close();
        }

        System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch sw = new System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch();
        sw.Start();
        using (TarInputStream s = new TarInputStream(File.OpenRead(str[2])))
        {
            TarEntry theEntry;

            String[] myArray = (String[])myList.ToArray(typeof(string));

            for (int i = 0; i < myArray.Length-1; i++)
            {
                Thread[] test = new Thread[myArray.Length];

                while ((theEntry = s.GetNextEntry()) != null)
                {

                    string directoryName = "";
                    string pathToTar = "";
                    pathToTar = theEntry.Name;

                    if (pathToTar != "")
                        directoryName = Path.GetDirectoryName(pathToTar) + "\\";

                    string fileName = Path.GetFileName(pathToTar);

                    Directory.CreateDirectory(str[1] + directoryName);

                    if (fileName != "")
                    {
                        if ((File.Exists(str[1] + directoryName + fileName)) || (!File.Exists(str[1] + directoryName + fileName)))
                        {
                            using (FileStream streamWriter = File.Create(str[1] + directoryName + fileName))
                            {
                                int size = 2048;
                                int count = 0;
                                List<byte[]> mydatalist = new List<byte[]>();

                                byte[] mydataArray = new byte[2048];
                                while (true)
                                {
                                    byte[] data = new byte[2048];
                                    size = s.Read(data, 0, data.Length);

                                    if (size > 0)
                                    {
                                        mydatalist.Add(data);
                                    }
                                    else
                                    {
                                        break;
                                    }
                                }
                                test[i] = new Thread(() =>
                                   StreamWriterFun(pathToTar, args, mydatalist)
                                );
                                test[i].Start();
                                streamWriter.Close();
                            }
                        }
                    }   
                }
            }
            s.Close();
            System.IO.File.Delete(str[2]); // delete the tar file
        }
        sw.Stop();
        string result1 = sw.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds.ToString();
        Console.WriteLine(result1);
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("error1");
    } 
}
```

Is there another way to write data from compreesion into new file? Not use streamWriter.

Comment: What problem did you find? Can you share the code? May be we can help you to resolve the problem

Comment: This is likely to be slower than not using threads.

Comment: Yes,use thread is unavoidable, but there is no way in the thread does not use streamwriter?

Answer (score 1):

The StreamReader and StreamWriter both especially designed to work with text streams. You will have more control if you switch to use the [FileStream](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filestream(v=vs.110).aspx).
Another option just to use [File.Create("fileName")](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d62kzs03(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
public static void WriteTo(string targetFile, Stream inputStream)
{
    using (var fileStream = File.Create(targetFile))
    {
        inputStream.CopyTo(fileStream);
    }
}
```